# HDF5 Library and Header version mismatch

Tags: unix, version, hdf5, mismatch

I received the following error message:

Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.8.15, library is 1.8.13

Last time I didn't realize that the server has already installed HDF5 1.8.13. I installed another HDF5 1.8.15 in my local directory. After discovering that the server had HDF 1.8.13 and it was already linked to other related softwares, I just deleted the whole directory for the HDF5 1.8.15 without "make clean" the HDF 1.8.15 and I don't have the right to change the HDF5 1.8.13 directory on the server. So how could I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!